# Regular expression for line match without specific word

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to create regular expression that math only lines that not containing specific word at the beginning of the line. In my case "deamon:".

```
My regex: (?!d)(?!e)(?!a)(?!m)(?!o)(?!n)(?!:).*\n
```

But this match the rest of line behind "deamon:" too, what I don't want.

**Input:**

```
deamon: parsing arguments...
deamon: parsing xml file...
deamon: creating xml file for demo...
deamon: executing demo
parsing arguments...
path to xml: /home/www/www/seg-chapter/tests/users/1/launches/60/demo.xml
parsing xml file...
```

**Match:**

```
parsing arguments...
parsing xml file...
creating xml file for demo...
executing demo
parsing arguments...
path to xml: /home/www/www/seg-chapter/tests/users/1/launches/60/demo.xml
parsing xml file...
```

**I want only:**

```
parsing arguments...
path to xml: /home/www/www/seg-chapter/tests/users/1/launches/60/demo.xml
parsing xml file...
```

Do you anybody know how to match only lines without "deamon:" at the beginning of the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.match( /^(?!deamon:).*/mg )
```

The multiline flag `m` means `^` matches the start of each line rather than just the start of the string.
`(?!deamon:)` is a negative look-ahead which prevents a match if a line starts with `deamon:`.